# Eliminar una fila según el valor de una columna en un dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo el siguiente dataframe:

```
   nombre             deporte
0  Sergio             fútbol
1  Antonio            surf
2  Juan               baloncesto
3  Sara               tenis
4  Anna               motor
```

Lo que pretendo hacer es eliminar esas filas donde la longitud de la palabra en la columna deporte sea igual a 5.

He probado lo siguiente:

```
    for dep in df['deporte']:
        if len(dep) == 5:
            df.drop(df[df['deporte'] == dep].index)

    df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

El problema que tengo es que el dataframe se queda igual y no elimina las filas, que en este caso serían las dos últimas. Por qué no lo hace bien?

Answer (score 2):

No hace falta que recorras el dataframe, no es nada eficiente.

Lo que puedes hacer es asignar a un nuevo dataframe el valor que no quieres filtrado. Te pongo el ejemplo:

```
df_filter = df[df["Deporte"].str.len() != 5]
```

En él, haces una máscara del df, y pasas la serie a str y coges los datos de Deporte que no tengan 5 de longitud.

Espero te haya servido de ayuda. Un saludo

Comment: Una solución muy elegante

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he entendido perfectamente y me ha sido de gran ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes eliminar las filas con el método *drop* sin la necesidad de realizar una iteración o crear otro *dataFrame*, primeramente te dejo [este enlace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas-dataframe-drop) para la documentación de drop, extraigo lo que nos dice traducido al español:

> Elimine filas o columnas especificando los nombres de las etiquetas y el eje correspondiente, o especificando directamente el índice o los nombres de las columnas. Cuando se utiliza un índice múltiple, las etiquetas de diferentes niveles se pueden eliminar especificando el nivel.

Para tu caso una forma de hacerlo sin instanciar otro *dataFrame* seria obteniendo los índices primero y enviar estos índices al método *drop* de la siguiente forma:

```
# Obtenemos los índices para los que la columna deporte tengan longitud de 5
indexNames = df[df['deporte'].str.len() == 5].index
# Eliminamos los índices encontrados
df.drop(indexNames, inplace = True)
```

Finalmente te  dejo un ejemplo funcional:

```
import pandas as pd

lista = [
    ('Sergio', 'fútbol'),
    ('Antonio', 'surf'),
    ('Juan', 'baloncesto'),
    ('Sara', 'tenis'),
    ('Anna', 'motor')
]
df = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns = ['nombre', 'deporte'])

# Obtenemos los índices para los que la columna deporte tengan longitud de 5
indexNames = df[df['deporte'].str.len() == 5].index
# Eliminamos los índices encontrados
df.drop(indexNames, inplace = True)
print(df)
```

Mostrándote el siguiente resultado:

> ```
>     nombre     deporte
> 0   Sergio      fútbol
> 1  Antonio        surf
> 2     Juan  baloncesto
> ```

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)

Answer (score -1):

Si te puedo dar un consejo, no modifiques los DataFrames, crea uno nuevo.
Otro consejo, nunca uses `inplace`, si no me equivoco su uso está desinsentivado.

```
(
    df
    .assign(len_sport=lambda df: df.deporte.str.len())
    .query('len_sport != 5')
    .drop('len_sport', axis=1)
)
```